# Books / Guides / Courses for mixed model?

Tags: mixed-model, references, experiment-design, glmm

I have started working for a pharmaceutical firm as a junior statistician recently . In the daily basis I work with lots of studies where I have to apply the mixed models in order to demonstrate the equivalence or difference between 2 groups, given the experimental design (with presence of random factor, repeated measures, etc). Tbh I feel a bit lost, that is why I am looking for some books / courses so I can learn more about the mixed model. Below are what I would like to achieve:

- For a given design, know what to put in the model (e.g in SAS know how to write the model with the right syntax). I would also like to know how to set up a specific design in order to respond the request of the client.
- Understand the formulas and calculation, be able to interpret the results and to troubleshoot if there are problems.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you